# PHP Parse error, help needed

Tags: php, syntax-error

hello in my ubuntu machine with my brand new apache2 server (mod php) a have this test.php

```
 <?php
    if($_GET***91;'foo'***93; == '</test>'){
        exit();
    }
 ?>
```

however when i do a get request then i saw this in the apache logs :

```
[Sun Feb 06 16:47:51 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '*' in /var/www/test.php on line 2
```

any ideas???
thnx in advance

Comment: The `***91` is supposed to be an opening bracket `[` and the other a closing one. Your PHP file is broken for some reason

Comment: You are getting syntax error because it's syntax error

Comment: It was probably `&#91;` as copied from a website. Would be interesting to know how it got transformed to three asterisks. Where did you find the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    if($_GET['foo'] == '</test>') {
        exit();
    }
?>
```